# How to create column based on other column and probably using regex in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

df:

```
Id   Product_description     Vol
100  Oil 32cmX36cmx25cm 1s   1  
101  Oil 32cmX36cmx30cm 1M   1
102  bag 45cmx3f 1s          1
103  bag 45cmx32f 2L         2
104  BAG 45cmx32f 3 L        3
105  BELT 135L 50S           50
106  BELT 194L 50S           NaN
107  BELT 194L 50 L#144      NaN
108  BELT L                  NaN
```

I need to do two things here:

1. Replace NaN from Vol Column.(Last digit followed by unit like 'L','S')
2. Create another column 'Unit' based on Vol & Product_description column.

Output:

```
Id   Product_description     Vol  Unit(Check Vol and get Unit from Product_description)
100  Oil 32cmX36cmx25cm 1s   1     s 
101  Oil 32cmX36cmx30cm 1M   1     M
102  bag 45cmx3f 1s          1     s
103  bag 45cmx32f 2L         2     L
104  BAG 45cmx32f 3 L        3     L
105  BELT 135L 50S           50    S
106  BELT 194L 50S           50    S
107  BELT 194L 50 L#144      50    L
107  BELT L                  NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex with named capturing groups, `extractall` to get all matches and `groupby`+`last` to keep the last one, then `join` to the original dataframe:

```
(df
 .drop(columns='Vol')
 .join(df['Product_description']
      .str.extractall('(?P<Vol>\d+)\s*(?P<Unit>[a-zA-Z]+)')
      .groupby(level=0).last()
      )
)
```

output:

```
    Id    Product_description  Vol Unit
0  100  Oil 32cmX36cmx25cm 1s    1    s
1  101  Oil 32cmX36cmx30cm 1M    1    M
2  102         bag 45cmx3f 1s    1    s
3  103        bag 45cmx32f 2L    2    L
4  104       BAG 45cmx32f 3 L    3    L
5  105          BELT 135L 50S   50    S
6  106          BELT 194L 50S   50    S
7  107     BELT 194L 50 L#144   50    L
8  108                 BELT L  NaN  NaN
```

*NB. the above ignores the original "Vol" column and simply extract the data again from scratch. If by any chance you don't want to overwrite potentially different values (they wouldn't match the string though), you could do:*

```
df2 = (df['Product_description']
      .str.extractall('(?P<Vol>\d+)\s*(?P<Unit>[a-zA-Z]+)')
      .groupby(level=0).last()
      )
df.combine_first(df2)
```